# Unable to use the "Docker push" command with ECR

Tags: docker, bamboo, amazon-ecs

I am unable to use the "Docker" task in Bamboo to push a Docker image up to AWS Elastic Container Repository (ECR) due to an ECR login issue. My output looks like this:

```
build   18-Oct-2016 12:11:54    9007f5987db3: Preparing
build   18-Oct-2016 12:11:54    b718b2f27b6c: Waiting
build   18-Oct-2016 12:11:54    c986610bcfe6: Waiting
build   18-Oct-2016 12:11:54    ee16ea28e998: Waiting
build   18-Oct-2016 12:11:54    a709d74a4732: Waiting
build   18-Oct-2016 12:11:54    c672d981aff9: Waiting
build   18-Oct-2016 12:11:54    17287d14d5b6: Waiting
build   18-Oct-2016 12:11:54    4505f2891620: Waiting
build   18-Oct-2016 12:11:54    94102dff0575: Waiting
build   18-Oct-2016 12:11:54    e83e87cb73c3: Waiting
build   18-Oct-2016 12:11:54    740e5e49ea89: Waiting
build   18-Oct-2016 12:11:54    092e6cb28bdb: Waiting
build   18-Oct-2016 12:11:54    9007f5987db3: Waiting
build   18-Oct-2016 12:11:54    8d94959a46f4: Waiting
build   18-Oct-2016 12:11:54    d2ccc68b6943: Waiting
build   18-Oct-2016 12:11:54    3dc6be5926c6: Waiting
build   18-Oct-2016 12:11:54    0afc75223403: Waiting
build   18-Oct-2016 12:11:54    71caa5138f3c: Waiting
build   18-Oct-2016 12:11:54    1be454502782: Waiting
build   18-Oct-2016 12:11:54    4a2173830433: Waiting
error   18-Oct-2016 12:11:54    error parsing HTTP 403 response body: invalid character 'Y' looking for beginning of value: "Your Authorization Token has expired. Please run 'aws ecr get-login' to fetch a new one."
simple  18-Oct-2016 12:11:54    Failing task since return code of [/bin/sh /tmp/WEB-SYNAPICI-JOB1-11-ScriptBuildTask-245668070788779382.sh] was 1 while expected 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that the `aws ecr get-login` command was generating a URL prefixed by `https://`. In order to get Bamboo pushing to my repository, I had to switch from using the Bamboo task to use a custom bash script that strips the "https://" off the front of the `docker login` command, so that the repository that is being logged into has exactly the same URL as the repository that is being pushed to.

I feel like this is probably a bug with the AWS client, but here's my script in case anyone else finds it useful:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
docker_login_command=$(aws ecr get-login)
$(echo $docker_login_command | sed 's|https://||' | sed 's|-e none ||')
container_id=$(docker images | grep foo | awk '{print $3;}' | uniq)
echo $container_id
url="output-of-the-ecr-create-repository-command.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bar/foo"
docker tag $container_id $url
docker push $url
```

Comment: I would be interested to know if anyone has a more elegant solution than dropping back to a bash script. I also feel like the output of the `aws ecr get-login` command should actually log you into the exact same repository that you need to run `docker push` successfully.

Comment: This was actually also the solution to a problem where `docker` responded that `"no such repository"` existed.

Answer (score 0):

> 

I would be interested to know if anyone has a more elegant solution than dropping back to a bash script.

If you are looking for a non script based solution, you might be interested in Utoolity's [Identity Federation for AWS (Bamboo)](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/net.utoolity.atlassian.bamboo.identity-federation-for-aws-bamboo/server/overview) add-on (commercial, see disclaimer), which provides a dedicated [Amazon ECR Credentials Variables](https://utoolity.atlassian.net/wiki/display/IFAWS/Using+the+Amazon+ECR+Credentials+Variables+task+in+Bamboo) task to *inject temporary Amazon Elastic Container Registry (Amazon ECR) authentication credentials for other tools and AWS unaware tasks like the Bamboo Docker task*.

Specifically, it creates the following variables which you can reference  wherever you need ECR credentials in subsequent tasks (provided they properly support Bamboo variables):

```
${bamboo.custom.aws.ecr.proxyEndpointDomain}
${bamboo.custom.aws.ecr.username}
${bamboo.custom.aws.ecr.password}
```

Please refer to [How to push a Docker image to a repository in your Amazon ECR registry with the Bamboo Docker task](https://utoolity.atlassian.net/wiki/display/UAAKB/How+to+push+a+Docker+image+to+a+repository+in+your+Amazon+ECR+registry+with+the+Bamboo+Docker+task) for a step-by-step guide.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the co-founder of this add-on's vendor, Utoolity.